# How do I get zsh-navigation-tools to show in the default shell colors instead of using its own theme?

Tags: zsh, theme, oh-my-zsh, plugin

I have a terminal with a white background:

[image: terminal showing 'cd' with white background]

I enabled the [zsh-navigation-tools plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/zsh-navigation-tools) in Oh My Zsh. In `n-list.conf` I've set the color scheme to black on white:

```
# Main color pair (foreground/background)
local colorpair="black/white"
```

But when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, the ncurses-like history search is still in a different color from my terminal:

[image: terminal with zsh-navigation-tools history search with grey background]

How can I get the history search in the same color?

Answer (score 0):

Set the colorscheme in `n-list.conf` to `default/default`:

```
# Main color pair (foreground/background)
local colorpair="default/default"
```

Resulting in:

[image: terminal with zsh-navigation-tools history search with white background]

Source: `zshmodules` man page, under `zcurses attr`:

> Each `fg_col`/`bg_col` attribute (to be read as '`fg_col` on `bg_col`') sets the foreground and background color for character output. The color **default** is sometimes available (in particular if the library is ncurses), specifying the foreground or background color with which the terminal started.  The color pair **default/default** is always available.